# Doctrine2 DQL join with unrelated tables to fetch both entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

My DQL query returns only the FROM object, which is nice if the other object were related, but it isn't.

My Query:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT c, s FROM MyBundle:Person c, MyBundle:Spot s 
JOIN s.geo_data g JOIN g.features f WHERE f.active = true AND 
ST_Distance(f.location, c.location) < :distance GROUP BY c, s');
```

This works perfectly in SQL, giving me all the spots and all the persons within :distance of them. But in DQL, it only returns the person object, and since on the database level they are not related, I have no way to fetch the correct spot.

My database setup is correct, I'm using a PostGIS backend and spots and persons *are not related in any way*. They just happen to be on the same map and I'm querying for spatial relationships.

According to documentation, it's intended behaviour, from what I read, s is being hydrated, but not returned anywhere at all, good job!

How can I teach DQL to please return me what I told it in SELECT? Where's the "I mean what I say, stop being a smartass" switch?

Comment: So what do you expect Doctrine to do?  Without a relation then how do you expect Doctrine to know they are related?  I think you will be on your own as far as hydrating goes.

Comment: I expect Doctrine to do what I tell it: select C **and** S. If I wanted just C, I'd have said "SELECT c FROM ...", wouldn't I?

Comment: @Tom do you have a relationship in doctrine, but not in the actual schema? Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: You could use a NativeQuery with ResultSetMapping. This will allow you to map each field to an Entity. See this example: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder

Comment: > A common mistake for beginners is to mistake DQL for being just some form of SQL and therefore trying to use table names and column names or join arbitrary tables together in a query. You need to think about DQL as a query language for your object model, not for your relational schema.

Comment: Yeroon comes closest to providing a useable answer. Do you want to write it up with one or two lines of how to do it as an answer to win the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine cannot give you both entities if they are not related because if the were related you would get the first entity c where you could get s through the relation.

What you can try is selecting all fields of both entities like

```
SELECT c.location, ...,  s.geo_data, ...
```

This will give you an array for each column that contains all fields from both entities.
Maybe you can use result set mapping to get the entities if desired.

Comment: That might actually work for some places in my code, but not all.

Comment: Turns out this seems to be the only way to get a result at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stuck with Doctrine, you HAVE TO define a OneToMany relation between places and people. In this way, you could set up the PeopleRepository and set up a method like getPeopleByLocationAndMaxDistance(Location $location, $distance)

```
SELECT p
FROM People AS p
LEFT JOIN Places AS pl
WHERE ST_Distance(p.location, pl.location) < :distance
```